# In my android project there are two classes and there is a button on first class,i need to view next page when i click on the button.

Tags: java, android

In my android project there are two classes and there is a button on first class,i need to view next page  when i click on the button.

package com.example.restaurantapp;

```
import android.os.Bundle;    
import android.app.Activity;     
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class RestaurantActivity extends Activity {
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
        Button orderbutton=(Button)findviewById(R.layout.activity_first);
        orderbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener());
    }
    private Button findviewById(int activityFirst) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_first, menu);
        { 
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RestaurantActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }


        return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the button you are referring to is `orderbutton`, you need to make the `OnClickListener` actually do something when the button is clicked:

```
     orderbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // use an Intent to go to the second Activity
         }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first activity set the listener on the button and in it starts the second activity with an explicit intent:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(
    new OnClickListener(){
        startActivity( new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class) );
    };
);
```